# Override an SCons builder

Tags: scons

I want to do some post-processing on all `.o` files (e.g. those generated by the `Object` or `StaticObject` Builders), no matter what Builder is used by the user.

I'm trying to "override" or "hook" the base environment's builders like so, but I can't come up with anything that works:

```python
old = env['BUILDERS']['StaticObject']
env['BUILDERS']['StaticObject'] = something_that_calls(old)
```

Is there a prescribed way to hook or override something like the `StaticObject` builder?

I've seen the question about a [Nested SCons Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941641/nested-scons-builder), but it doesn't tell me how to replace an existing builder, only supplementing its behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if there is a blessed way to replace a Builder, but I think you're on the right track. The following (admittedly trivial) example works for me:

```python
def wrap_builder(bld):    
    return Builder(action = [bld.action, 'echo $TARGET'],
                   suffix = bld.suffix,
                   src_suffix = bld.src_suffix)

obj_bld = env['BUILDERS']['Object']
env['BUILDERS']['Object'] = wrap_builder(obj_bld)

env.Program('test', ['test.c'])
```

with output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o test.o -c -std=c99 test.c
echo test.o
test.o
gcc -o test test.o
scons: done building targets.
```

As you can see, the additional (echo) action is performed after building the object file.

Comment: Awesome - I was getting hung up on the "copy constructor" instantiation of the wrapper builder. I was just thinking to myself "I wonder if there's a `Builder.Clone()`"  I'll give this a try.

Comment: `<offtopic>`Also, "low-power wireless networking systems" - 802.15.4 by chance?`</offtopic>`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, I work on: http://www.linear.com/products/wireless_sensor_networks_-_dust_networks

Comment: Your solution seemed to work perfectly. I'm not sure if it is necessary, but I also passed the following members from the original Builder to the wrapper: `prefix`, `ensure_suffix`, `(target|source)_(scanner|factory)`, `emitter`, `multi`, `env`, `src_builder`, and `single_source`. Again, really a shame they don't provide a `Clone()`.

Comment: Regarding the Clone() method: we (SCons) are an open-source project, so your pull requests are welcome anytime. ;)